# MySQL how to return concatenated name and lastname of a user

Tags: mysql, sql

I need my MySQL query return "**value**" and "**label**" field name.

I would like to have "**value**" as id of user and "**label**" as "*name lastname*" or "*name_first_letter lastname*" directly from the query.

Lets say I have a table like this:

- **id name    lastname**
- 1  John    Johhanson
- 2  Peter   Petterson
- 3  Jeff    Jefferson

I get the ID as "value" by a simple query: `SELECT id as value`. I would also like to get "J. Johhanson" or "P. Petterson" as "*label*".

**UPDATE**

Sorry for bothering. I tried **CONCAT**, **CONCAT_WS**. Initially unsuccessfully, but now managed to get the results easily. 
In my case this query worked as I needed:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', name, lastname ) FROM users
WHERE name LIKE  "%Peter%"
```

Thank you.

Comment: -1 for no effort at all, not even a look at the documentation, on the asker's side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id                                    AS value, 
       Concat(LEFT(name, 1), '. ', lastname) AS label 
FROM   table;
```